# Azure Cloud: Use of a single tenant vs. multiple tenants in a global business scenario

Tags: azure, multi-tenant

I am looking for a kind of best practise approach here:

I have a client that actually has multiple independent legal entities (read companies) throughout the globe. They are planning on implementing a new ERP solution in the Cloud (preferable Azure) and where are faced with the following question:

Should we create one single tenant and deploy in that all instances for all group companies? Or should we go with each a dedicated tenant for the European group companies and dedicated tenant for the US companies and dedicated tenant for the Asian group companies?

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

All the best,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest to go with the `Multi-Tenancy` Model which comes with the following benefits.

1. Client specific customization (tenant per law office)
2. Feature rollout based on the tenant (small tenant can choose a subscription with limited features and large tenant can opt for more features in the planned ERP rollout)
3. Easy to charge the tenant's for using your ERP platform
4. Metering and billing and billing options like pre-paid, post-paid / pay-as-you-go models
5. Easy provisioning in the regions where the tenant lives, low latency and other advantages
6. Data compliance accordingly to the law of the land
7. Better security and tenant specific authentication integration like with their IDP etc.

There are so many benefits not limited to the ones given above when you prefer to go with a tenancy model.